# Looking for help in understanding an alternate syntax for creating a list using a for loop

Tags: python

Original Syntax:

```
word = "apple"
letters = [word[i] for i in range(len(word))]
print(letters)
```

I recently stumbled on the above syntax that outputs a list containing all the characters in a string

I am a beginner and have not understood how this type of syntax works.

I know how list splicing works and am familiar with the range() and len() methods. But so far in my learning, I have only seen the standard syntax with regards to for loops.

For instance, the below code prints all the characters on a new line

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    print(word[i])
```

Could anyone help me understand how the original syntax works or guide me to the relevant documentation?

Comment: It's called "list comprehension".

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: @chess W3Schools is generally pretty bad for Python. Check out the official tutorial instead: [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: never knew that @wjandrea, I find them helpful, but I will do think the official tutorial is better.